# Use of option helper in Play Framework 2.0 templates

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to use `views.html.helper.select` (documentation [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/scala/index.html#views.html.helper.select)). I don't know scala, so i'm using java. I need to pass object of type Seq[(String)(String)] to the template right? Something like:

```
@(fooForm:Form[Foo])(optionValues:Seq[(String)(String)])

@import helper._

@form(routes.foo){
  @select(field=myForm("selectField"),options=optionValues)
}
```

I don't know how to create Seq[(String)(String)] in java. I need to fill this collection with pairs (id,title) from my enum class.

Can somebody show me some expample how to use the select helper?

I found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/play-framework/9-dYG1wZkS0) thread on users group, but Kevin's answer didn't helped me a lot.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The right type is: `Seq[(String, String)]`. It means a sequence of pairs of String. In Scala there is a way to define pairs using the arrow: `a->b == (a, b)`. So you could write e.g.:

```scala
@select(field = myForm("selectField"), options = Seq("foo"->"Foo", "bar"->"Bar"))
```

But there is another helper, as shown in the documentation, to build the sequence of select options: `options`, so you can rewrite the above code as:

```scala
@select(myForm("selectField"), options("foo"->"Foo", "bar"->"Bar"))
```

In the case your options values are the same as their label, you can even shorten the code to:

```scala
@select(myForm("selectField"), options(List("Foo", "Bar")))
```

(note: in Play 2.0.4 `options(List("Foo", "Bar"))` doesn't compile, so you can try this `options(Seq("Foo", "Bar"))`)

To fill the options from Java code, the more convenient way is to use either the overloaded [`options`](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/scala/index.html#views.html.helper.options$) function taking a `java.util.List<String>` as parameter (in this cases options values will be the same as their label) or the overloaded function taking a `java.util.Map<String, String>`.

Comment: Thank you very much for response. But this doesn't solve my problem. I need to create the collection and fill it with values in Java and then pass that collection into scala template.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your problem, indeed. I updated my answer to suggest ways to fill the options from Java code.

Comment: `options(List("Foo", "Bar"))` did not typecheck for me so I used `@myOptions= @{List("Foo", "Bar").map(str => str->str)}`