# Populate a html drop down list in play framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use of option helper in Play Framework 2.0 templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127156/use-of-option-helper-in-play-framework-2-0-templates)

Normal html code:

```
                        <select id = "game_duration">          
                        <option>01 hour</option>
                        <option>02 hour</option>
                        <option>03 hour</option>
                        <option>04 hour</option>
                        <option>05 hour</option>
                        <option>Never end</option>
                        </select>
```

To @select of Play framework... 

I tried following [Tutorial](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/tags#select) but it only printed plain html of the @select tag..

I'm new to play thus can anyone please help me?

 Thank you very much.

Comment: Why are you pointing tutorials for Play 1.0 when definitely asking for Play 2.0??? They are absolutely not the same!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First import `helper` package(s) at the beginning of your view:

```
@import helper._
```

So you can use that sample:

```scala
@select(
   gameForm("game_duration"),
   options(Seq("01 hour","02 hour","03 hour","Never end")),
   '_label -> "Game duration", '_default -> "-- Select duration --"
)
```

Alternatively you can also use that code without previous importing `helper` package(s)

```scala
@helper.select(
   gameForm("game_duration"),
   helper.options(Seq("01 hour","02 hour","03 hour","Never end")),
   '_label -> "Game duration", '_default -> "-- Select duration --"
)
```

**important:** Try to use `options(List("01 hour","02 hour","03 hour","Never end"))` if `Seq(...)` version will fail while compiling.

btw, most probably it would be better using numeric values (ie `int` - easier to store and search in DB):

```
...
helper.options("60" -> "01 hour","120" -> "02 hour","180" -> "03 hour", "9999" -> "Never end"),
...
```

Also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10137190/1066240) for more samples

Comment: it said that "Object List is not a value
[error]              options(List("01 hour",...

Comment: still got error object List is not a value
[error]              options = options(List("01 hour","02 hour","03 hour","Never end")),
 :(

Comment: Sorry because i didnot look careful, but is this example for play 1.0 ? I'm suing play 2.04 and still got same error object List is not a value

Comment: Ach, I've tested all samples and now they are correct, don't know when it was changed, but it seems that `options(List("one", "two"))` doesn't work in 2.0.4 and `options(Seq("one", "two"))` works.

Comment: `options(Seq("one","two"))` fails on 2.0.3 but `options(List("one","two"))` works on 2.0.3