# How to prefill a dropdown using scala template and play framework

Tags: scala, playframework, scala-template

I am using scala template and Play 2.0 framework for my project. Let's say I have a user form with fields like name (textfield), age (dropdown). While creating the user I filled name as dave and selected age as 25.

Now on my edit screen, I want my values to be prefilled, i know how to do it with textfield (i.e. set value as userForm('name')) but what about the dropdown? how to do it.

Comment: I think this has already been answered:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12798174/populate-a-html-drop-down-list-in-play-framework

Comment: No @shawn, I just went through the link, it is telling how to create a dropdown using scala template helper, but not to set the prefilled values.

Comment: What kind of dropdown are you talking about ? HTML's `select` tag or things like Bootstrap's dropdown? for `select` tag, link suggested is valid one... describe what do you mean by _prefilled_?

Comment: Well, I am using `@select` (which is a scala helper ) and prefilled simply means, if a user had entered his age as 25 (via dropdown) then on the edit screen his age should be shown as 25 when the page loads. Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Shawn Downs and biesior.

Well, we can use `@select` scala helper class to show the pre-filled result.
like.

```
 @select(userForm("age"),models.Age.values().toList.map(v => (v.getDisplayName(), v.getDisplayName())),'id->"age")
```

To show other options I have used an enum of possible values of age.

Answer (score 0):

In your model there will be 2 fields

Model code

```
Class User{
   public String name;
   public int age;
}
```

Controller code

```
.
.
.
Form<User> userForm = Form.form(User.class);
User user = new User();
user.name = "Albert";
user.age = 19;

userForm.fill(user);
.
.
.
```

Util code

```
package utils;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

public class DropdownUtils {

    public static HashMap<String, String> getAgeList(int ageLimit){
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> ageList = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        for(Integer i=0; i<=ageLimit; i++){
            ageList.put(i.toString(), i.toString());
        }

        return ageList;
    }
}
```

View code

```
.
.
.
<form>
@helper.inputText(userForm("name"))
@helper.select(userForm("age"),
                helper.options(utils.DropdownUtils.getAgeList(25)))
</form>
.
.
.
```