# Get selected value from selector (@Select) in controller. Java Play Framework

Tags: java, model-view-controller, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to get a selected value in my controller but can't get it to work.

In my view I have a form:

```
@(infoObjectForm: Form[Infoobject],nav: String = "")

@form(routes.Admin.admin_createMapInstance()) {
        <fieldset>
        @select(
                infoObjectForm("infoobjectId"), 
                options(Infoobject.all_values), 
                'id -> "infoobjects_field",
                '_label -> "Infoobject", '_default -> "--Select Infoobject--",
                '_showConstraints -> false, 'value -> infoObjectForm
            )
        </fieldset>

        <div class="actions">
            <input type="submit" value="Create this Map Instance" class="btn primary"> or 
            <a href="@routes.Admin.admin_MapInstance()" class="btn">Cancel</a> 
        </div>
    }
```

This dropdown shows all my info objects. When I choose one and hit the submit button, I want to use the selected infoobject (and it's properties) in the controller.

```
Form<Infoobject> mapForm = form(Infoobject.class).bindFromRequest();
        if(mapForm.hasErrors()) {
            flash("error", "MapForm contains an error");
            return badRequest(createMapForm.render(mapForm, ""));
        }
Infoobject infoobject = mapForm.get();
String desig = infoobject.getDesignation();
String desc = infoobject.getDescription();
...
```

The mapForm has errors. Do you guys know why?

Infoobject model:

```
@Entity
public class Infoobject extends Model {
@Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="infoobject_seq", sequenceName="infoobject_id_seq", allocationSize=1000)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="infoobject_seq")
    public Long infoobjectId;

    @Required
    public String designation;
    @Required
    public String description;
        ...getters/setters
```

I've tried using two @inputText fields in my view, so I could create a info object, that works. But now I wan't to create a map instance of an existing info object.

Appreciate your help!

**EDIT:** Printed the error in console, saying "error.required". Anyone? It seems that the form doesn't contain any Infoobject. Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15104905/play-framework-select-input-validation?lq=1) simular question/answer..so why does this not work?

Comment: likely you have other fields in your model or a field name doesn't match... maybe show your `Infoobject` model code

Comment: Can you show the Infoobject model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution work, but I don't think this is the best way.

```
<form>
        @select(
                infoObjectForm("infoobjectId.id"), 
                options(Infoobject.all_values), 
                'id -> "infoobjects_field",
                '_label -> "Infoobject", '_default -> "--Select Infoobject--",
                '_showConstraints -> false
            )
        <div class="actions">
            <input type="button" value="Create this Map Instance" class="btn primary" onclick="JavaScript:createMap()"> or 
            <a href="@routes.Admin.admin_MapInstance()" class="btn">Cancel</a> 
        </div>
    </form>
    <script>
        function createMap() {
            var ioId = document.getElementById('infoobjects_field').value;
            if(ioId) {
                var nextUrl = "/CreateMapInstance?ioId="+ioId;
                window.location = nextUrl;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

I'll do a GET and sends just the ID in the url instead of sending the whole infoobject in a POST.

Answer (score 0):

In the @select tag put infoObjectForm("infoobjectId")

In the model class Infoobject add this:

```
static {
    play.data.format.Formatters.register(Infoobject.class, new ClassFormatter());
}

public static class ClassFormatter extends SimpleFormatter<Infoobject> {

    @Override
    public Infoobject parse(String text, Locale locale) {
        if (text == null || text.trim().length() == 0)
            return null;
        return Infoobject.find.byId(Long.parseLong(text.trim()));
    }

    @Override
    public String print(Infoobject value, Locale locale) {
        return (value == null || value.id == null ? "" : value.id.toString());
    }
}
```